# Windows 3.1 Installer reinstalls old version right after uninstalling it rather than installing new upgrade

Tags: windows-xp, windows-installer

I have a MSI assembly which is an upgrade.  The Upgradecode remains the same between the previous release and the new upgrade assembly.  I also have the RemovePrevious attribute set so old version is removed before upgrade is installed.

I see the uninstallation of the old version occur as expected.  However, the Windows Installer 3.1 immediately turns around are attempts to re-install the old version again before it even proceeds to the new version.  I have verified this by changing the first custom installation dialog in the newer version and see it just fine on a first install of the new version.  But the dialog seen when upgrading is the old one which shipped with the previous release.  I even rebuilt the old release with message box displays to verify that Installer is indeed re-installing the old version right after the uninstall rather than moving on to the new upgrade version.

Using MSIExec does not reveal any errors being logged to explain this odd behaviour and I cannot find any documentation that helps to identify why this is occurring.

Anyone have any ideas on why this behaviour is happening and how to go about fixing it?

Comment: I should also mention that custom actions for install and uninstall are contained in a common steps.exe.  It's produced by a project as part of my VS 2005 solution.  There are no entry functions in the custom actions. So assuming correct calls are made by the following formal declarations to override the ones of the Installer:
protected override void OnBeforeInstall();
public override void Install();
public override void Uninstall();
As Uninstall() completes error free, it's unclear why Installer calls other two Install function custom actions rather then turning to the new upgrade assembly?

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the version number of your app/dll in the embedded resources.  The "new" behavior of the installer will not upgrade any exe/dlls unless the file versions have been bumped up.

Comment: Sorry it wasn't stated, I guess I thought it would be obvious, that in order to have the upgrade process even begin, the Version number and ProductCode would have to be increased along with both having the identical UpgradeCode.  Even increasing the Version without changing the ProductCode will not start the upgrade process, but rather invoke an error that an existing application already is installed and must be removed through the Add/Remove programs.